# How to share only the VPN tun0 network connection "to other computers"

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, network-manager, vpn

I'm trying to set up a proper VPN killswitch (ie a vpn-**only** internet connection) and I'm somewhat new to Linux. Tried to think of straightforward ways (asking [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436262/killswitch-block-all-connections-except-a-dynamic-ip-vpn-cant-use-iptables-if), [or here](https://superuser.com/questions/1309653/linux-block-all-connections-except-vpn-dynamic-ip-domain)), and came to the conclusion that the easiest thing is to use a Debian distro as a VM (virtualbox) (with usb wifi or ethernet dongles passed through), that handles the VPN connecting, and then share that VM's internet connection to the Host VM - but by internet I mean **only** the VPN connection, not the whole network connection.

But even on this avenue I hit a roadblock: how do you share tun0 only?

As I wrote in the linked questions, what I'm doing now is sharing the VM's whole internet connection, and it works. And I tried to do a killswitch with iptables (and failed because it's practically impossible because the VPN's IP is **dynamic**).

I want this VM to be my internet connection sandbox, in lieu of having PFSense, while on the go. How can I do this?